# Android: MessageBox not working

Tags: android

I am trying to do some data verification. In short, when an add button is pressed, if certain fields are not filled in then I want to display a message box and return from further processing.

This is the flow of my code without the messageBox code:

```
  Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {


            //local vars
            String access;
            String gender;
            String avail;
            String availCode;


            // getting values from selected editItems
            String name = textName.getText().toString();                
            String street = textStreet.getText().toString();                
            String city = textCity.getText().toString();                
            String state = textState.getText().toString();              
            String postal = textPostal.getText().toString();
            String country = textCountry.getText().toString();
            String directions = textDirections.getText().toString();
            String comments = textComments.getText().toString();


            //verify miniminal data
            if((name.equals("")) || (street.equals(""))|| (city.equals("")) || (state.equals("")) || (postal.equals("")) || (country.equals("")))
            {

            }
```

I tried pasting in this code:

```
        //verify miniminal data
        if((name.equals("")) || (street.equals(""))|| (city.equals("")) || (state.equals("")) || (postal.equals("")) || (country.equals("")))
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setTitle("Title");
            builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            builder.setMessage("Must enter minimal data.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                return;
              }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
```

But...I cannot get this line to build:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Eclipse is saying context cannot be resolved to a variable.

I am confused as to what to do. Can someone help?

Comment: Don't have my Android right in front of me, but the error is clear - `context` not defined. So, look at an example from developer.android.com re: AlertDialog and find out where your context variable should come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a `context` variable anywhere in the code above, and `AlertDialog.Builder`'s constructor needs a `Context` instance passed to it.

However, since you're doing this from an `OnClickListener`'s `onClick()`, you can use [`View#getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29) to get a `Context` instance.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
```

Comment: v is view in your case so write view.getContext